# Gsub transforming numbers

Tags: r, gsub

I find this problem >S
I scrap some data from the web and for instance I obtain this
`"3.444.654"`   (As character)
If I use `gsub("3.444.654", ".", "")` in order to get `3444654`... 
R gives me
`[1] ""`

What could I do to get the integer!

Comment: Try `as.numeric(gsub('.', '', "3.444.654" , fixed=TRUE))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> gsub(".", "", "3.444.654", fixed = TRUE)
[1] "3444654"
```

Maybe read the documentation for `gsub` for argument order etc. To then turn the string into a number, use `as.numeric`, `as.integer` etc.

Comment: Or just escape is using `\\.` though `fixed = TRUE` is better. Also, probably should wrap into `as.numeric". But definitely the best advice here is to read documentation.

Comment: @ErikMartinez If this fixed your problem it's customary on SO to accept the answer.